# Using int() with decimal numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, decimal

I have a piece of code for data validating user input to ensure only numbers greater than zero are taken, as below:

```
while True:
x = raw_input("Please enter a number greater than zero.")
try:
    x = int(x)
    num = True
except ValueError:
    print "Sorry, you entered an invalid input. Please ensure you enter only numbers  greater than zero."
if x > 0:
    if num == True:
            break
elif x <= 0:
    print "Sorry, you entered an invalid input for time. Please ensure you enter only positive numbers. \n"
```

However, this statement is catching decimal numbers greater than zero, which I want to allow through. What should I change in order to prevent this from happening?

P.S: Also, could anyone explain precisely *why* it's happening?

Comment: I think how I did it was change int to float and just assume everything is of float datatype? of course, you could try for an int, throw, try for a float, throw

Comment: This is vague. Please post working code, sample input, expected output and actual results.

Comment: What result do you want if the user inputs "0.5"?

Comment: That moment when a user asks a question and never returns...

Comment: Sorry, I had some family issues. I'm back now. What I want to do is have a user be able to give me any input, but for my program to throw up an error telling the user what they did wrong if they enter anything other than a number. I've edited the question to include working code now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use float instead int.
Float allow decimals and will raise an error for strings that are not numbers.

Comment: or use `int(float(user_input))` to get the int part of the float, if that is what you want. We are grasping at straws because the question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

As for the *why* this is happening part:

Using **int(value**) will always round the value downwards. Even a 0.99 would become 0, which is why your system is catching the decimals. Using **float**, as suggested by Martín Muñoz del Río, will not round, which is why it works.

As a side note, using

```
if num == True:
```

in your code could be simplified to

```
if num:
```

because you set num as a boolean value already (num = True) earlier.

Also, your code has an indentation error (code under the while loop isn't indented), but that's not such big of a deal right here I guess ;)

I hope I could help!

Comment: The indentation error occurred when I was typing the code into stackoverflow. Also, it was catching decimals greater than one - e.g 1.2, 6.66, ect. Any idea why _that_ was happening?